# How does a SQL injection working how to stop it

Tags: sql-injection

Recently I have been doing hackthissite.org and you have to use SQL injections quite a bit. I understand how to do them, but not how they work. I was wondering if anyone knew what the internal error is that causes it to do what it does.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) have plenty of information on the subject.

Comment: Frankly, if you do not know how they work, then you do not know how to do them.

Comment: i read on a website somewhere how to do them, I know it has something to do with errors